# Spring boot app not loading when deploying war on tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.10'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.4'
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
bootRepackage.enabled=false
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"



def jdkVersion = 1.8

sourceCompatibility = jdkVersion
targetCompatibility = jdkVersion

jettyRun {
     httpPort = 8080
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.all { set ->
    def jarTask = task("${set.name}Jar", type: Jar) {
        baseName = baseName + "-$set.name"
        from set.output
    }

    artifacts {
        archives jarTask
    }
}

dependencies{


     def springpluginCore="1.2.0.RELEASE"
     def hibernateVersion="5.2.10.Final"
     def sqlServerVersion="6.1.7.jre8-preview"
     def springfoxSwaggerVersion="2.7.0"
     def springfoxSwaggerUiVersion="2.7.0"
     def jsonPathVersion="2.2.0"
     def jsonSchemaVersion="2.6.3"
     def junitVersion="4.9"
     def mapstructVersion="1.1.0.Final"
     def mapstructProcessorVersion="1.1.0.Final"

      // Infra dependency
     compile project(':pointin-infrastructure')

     //spring dependencies
     compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")

     compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
     providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
  // compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
     compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
     compile group: 'org.springframework.plugin', name: 'spring-plugin-core', version: "${springpluginCore}"

     //datasource dependencies
     compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-gradle-plugin', version: "${hibernateVersion}"
     compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version:"${sqlServerVersion}"
     compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")


     //swagger springfox dependencies
     compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: "${springfoxSwaggerVersion}"
     compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: "${springfoxSwaggerUiVersion}"

     //other dependencies
     compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: "${jsonPathVersion}"
     compile group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct-jdk8', version: "${mapstructVersion}"
     apt "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}"    

     compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:$jsonSchemaVersion"    
     compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:"



     //test dependencies
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.9'
}
war {
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include 'application.properties'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir project(':pointin-infrastructure').file('src/main/java')
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
        output.classesDir   = 'build/classes/main/java'
        output.resourcesDir = 'build/classes/main/resources'
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/resources'
        }
        output.classesDir   = 'build/classes/test/java'
        output.resourcesDir = 'build/classes/test/resources'
    }

}
```

This is my main file

```
package com.dxc.pt.application.config;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am trying to deploy this on tomcat 8 but its not loading since I am not able to get the lib provided folder in the war.Please not that I am very new to gradle

Comment: All of the `sourceSets { }` block should be removed as it's either erroneous or only specifying the same values as the defaults. This: `srcDir project(':pointin-infrastructure').file('src/main/java')` is not how you depend on another project, you already have that when you do `compile project(':pointin-infrastructure')`.

Comment: I agree with @nickb, I think the sourceSets are mostly as conventions. I am curious this config: `bootRepackage.enabled=false`, why do we need that?

Comment: @chenrui bootreapackage.enabled is set as false because i dont need it and when enabled it gives me an exception "cant rename the dependent the jar"

Comment: any update on this? I think it would be better to paste some error logs here.

Answer (score 0):

It eventually started working after I reinstalled java.Found out it was the problem with the conflicting JAVA_HOME set in the environment variables.
Other than that eclipse exported war was not supporting gradle and producing a war inside a war instead of jar inside a war for subproject which gradle produces